# why is this loop running infinitely discord.py?

Tags: loops, discord, discord.py, bots

```
 users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
 users.pop(users.index(self.client.user))
 finaluser= users
 role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admins")
 print(finaluser)
 for user in users: //this is running infinitely
   await ctx.send(user.name)
   if role in user.roles:
     finaluser.append(user)
     await ctx.send(finaluser)
     return
```

Here why is this for loop running infinitely? I cannot understand

Comment: do either of the awaits return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fix it. Instead of assigning finaluser to users, I assigned it to
`finaluser= await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()`. Now, It's working as expected.